# Summing the counts in a data frame using sliding window

Tags: r, dataframe, sliding-window

I am new to R. I have a data frame in R like following

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep("A1",10),rep("A2",13),rep("A3",12)),
                 Values=c(10,2,4,23,10,5,20,15,13,21,15,9,19,5,14,25,18,19,31,26,4,21,4,6,7,12,15,18,25,20,16,29,21,19,10))
```

For every ID I would like to sum the counts in column "Values" in a sliding windows for every 3 positions. Following data frame is an excerpt from `df` which includes only the records corresponding to `A1`:

```
ID    Values
A1     10
A1      2
A1      4
A1     23
A1     10
A1      5
A1     20
A1     15
A1     13
A1     21
```

I would like to take 3 entries at time and sum and move to next 3 entries. When the sliding windows can't accommodate 3 entries then I skip those values.

For an example, `Window_1` starts from first value (`10`) while `window_2` starts from second value (`2`) and window_3 starts from third value (`4`).

```
 window_1 = [10+2+4] + [23+10+5] + [20+15+13] = 102 
 window_2 = [2+4+23] + [10+5+20] + [15+13+21] = 113
 window_3 = [4+23+10] + [5+20+15] = 77
```

and report it in a data frame like following:

```
ID  Window_1 Window_2 Window_3
A1   102       113      77
```

Likewise I would like sum the counts in column `Values` for everyid in the data frame "df" and report in a data.frmae like following:

```
ID    window_1   window_2   window_3
A1      102       113         77
A2      206       195         161
A3      198       163         175
```

I tried the following code

```
sum_win_3=0
sum_win_2=0
sum_win_1=0
win_1_counts=0
win_2_counts=0
win_3_counts=0

for (i in seq(1,length(df$Values),3))
{

  if((i+i+1+i+2) %% 3 == 0)
  {
    win_1_counts=df$Values[i]+df$Values[i+1]+df$Values[i+2]
    win_1_counts[is.na(win_1_counts)]=0
    #print(win_1_counts)
  }
  sum_win_1=sum_win_1+win_1_counts
}
#print(sum_win_1)

for (j in seq(2,length(df$Values),3))
{
  if((j+j+1+j+2) %% 3 == 0)
  {
    win_2_counts=df$Values[j]+df$Values[j+1]+df$Values[j+2]
    win_2_counts[is.na(win_2_counts)]=0
    #print(win_2_counts)
  }
  sum_win_2=sum_win_2+win_2_counts
}
#print(sum_win_2)

for (k in seq(3,length(df$Values),3))
{
  if((k+k+1+k+2) %% 3 == 0)
  {
    win_3_counts=df$Values[k]+df$Values[k+1]+df$Values[k+2]
    win_3_counts[is.na(win_3_counts)]=0
    #print(win_3_counts)
  }
  #sum_win_3=sum_win_3+win_3_counts
}
print(sum_win_3)
output=data.frame(ID=df[1],Window_1=sum_win_1,Window_2=sum_win_2,Window_3=sum_win_3)
```

The above code sums the counts for window_1, windows_2 and window_3 by taking all the IDs together rather working on every ID separately.
Kindly guide me in getting the the output in the desired format stated above.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are the start/end positions and the length of the windows the same for each ID?

Comment: You might look at the package `zoo` which has some rolling apply functions.  That may be less painful that writing your own (slow) loops.  Also consider looking for functions that calculate moving means.  You can convert a moving mean back to a moving sum by multiplying the mean by the number of observations that went into it.

Comment: Why in the third window for `A1` you are not also including 13 and 21?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Before I count, the window should have 3 values, if there is only 1 or 2, I skipped it.

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying. Aren't you counting until the end of the column by `ID` each time, while shifting the first value by one each time? Your first two windows were from position 1 to the end and from position two to the end. But the third window was from position 3 **not** until the end. I have a solution, but your logic isn't reflecting your desired output.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I take every ID and sum counts for every sliding window. Window_1 starts with first position and moves for every 3 positions, while and window_2 starts with position 2 and slides for every position until it reaches end and window_3 starts with position 3 and reaches until the end. Every window must be able to accommodate 3 entries. Let me know if you need more details

Comment: Window 1 **isn't** moving for every 3 position in `A1` (according to the calculations you showed, and window 3 **isn't** moving until the end according to the calculations you showed. The last value in `A1` is 21, while your calculation for window 3 ends at 15.

Comment: @DavidArenburg in A1, for window1, it takes first 3 entries(10+2+4), then it moves to 4th,5th,6th values(23+10+5), then it moves to 7th,8th,9th values(20+15+13), after 9th, there is only 1 entry, so it skips. Similarly for window_3 it starts with 3rd, 4th,5th positions(4+23+10), then it moves to 6th,7th and 8th values(5,20,15). After 8th position, there are only 2 entries so it skips. let me know if you need more details

Comment: I think the `A2` value for `window_3` needs to be `161` (see my answer & also calculated it by hand)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the *data.table* package, I would approach it as follows:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(w1 = sum(Values[1:(3*(.N%/%3))]),
              w2 = sum(Values[2:(3*((.N-1)%/%3)+1)]),
              w3 = sum(Values[3:(3*((.N-2)%/%3)+2)]))
          , by = ID]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    ID  w1  w2  w3
> 1: A1 102 113  77
> 2: A2 206 195 161
> 3: A3 198 163 175
> ```

Or to avoid the repetition (thanx to @Cath):

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(1:3, function(i) {sum(Values[i:(3*((.N-i+1)%/%3)+(i-1))])})
          , by = ID]
```

If you want to rename the V1, V2 & V3 variables, you can do that afterwards, but you can also do:

```
cols <- c("w1","w2","w3")

setDT(df)[, (cols) := lapply(1:3, function(i) {sum(Values[i:(3*((.N-i+1)%/%3)+(i-1))])})
          , by = ID]
```

Comment: more directly : `setDT(df)[, lapply(1:3, function(i) {sum(Values[i:(3*((.N-i+1)%/%3)+(i-1))])}), by = ID]
` (and avoiding the repetition ;-) )

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work:

```
library(zoo)
wins = function(x, w) 
  rollapply(x, width = w*((length(x)-seq(w)+1) %/% w), align = "left", sum)

aggregate(Values ~ ID, df, wins, 3)
#   ID Values.1 Values.2 Values.3
# 1 A1      102      113       77
# 2 A2      206      195      161
# 3 A3      198      163      175
```

This is the only answer so far to perform the calculation on a rolling basis, which is usually more efficient.

Answer (score 5):

This could be done using `tapply`and `aggregate`

```
sumf <- function(x1){
             sum(tapply(x1, 
                        (seq_along(x1) -1) %/%3, 
                        function(x) ifelse(length(x) == 3, sum(x), 0)))
        }

aggregate(Values ~ ID, data = df, 
          FUN = function(y){
              cbind(sumf(y), sumf(y[-1]), sumf(y[-c(1,2)]))
          })

#  Group.1 x.1 x.2 x.3
#1      A1 102 113  77
#2      A2 206 195 161
#3      A3 198 163 175
```

This can also be done using `filter`

```
sum.filter <- function(z) tapply(head(tail(as.numeric(
    filter(z, c(1,1,1))),-1), -1), 
    0:(length(z)-3) %% 3 +1, sum)

aggregate(Values ~ ID, data = df, FUN = function(y){ cbind(sum.filter(y) )})
```